# Kotlin equivalent for Java `? extends`

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to convert a module class(dagger) into a kotlin file but facing this issue when trying to build the kotlin converted code.

> @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type

This is where I am getting the issue.

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ClassKey(EnterEmailFragment::class)
abstract fun bindsEnterEmailInjector(injector: EnterEmailInjector): ScreenInjector<in Fragment, out Any>
```

Java Code:(Java code is working fine!)

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ClassKey(EnterEmailFragment.class)
abstract ScreenInjector<? extends Fragment, ? extends Object> bindsEnterEmailInjector(EnterEmailInjector injector);
```

And this is how .class file looks like

```
public abstract class com.gojek.driver.ulysses.email.di.EmailScreenFactoryModule {
  public static final com.gojek.driver.ulysses.email.di.EmailScreenFactoryModule$Companion Companion;

  public abstract com.gojek.driver.base.ScreenInjector<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, java.lang.Object> bindsEnterEmailInjector(com.gojek.driver.ulysses.email.di.EnterEmailInjector);

  public com.gojek.driver.ulysses.email.di.EmailScreenFactoryModule();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #16                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #42                 // class com/gojek/driver/ulysses/email/di/EmailScreenFactoryModule$Companion
       3: dup
       4: aconst_null
       5: invokespecial #49                 // Method com/gojek/driver/ulysses/email/di/EmailScreenFactoryModule$Companion."<init>":(Lkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V
       8: putstatic     #40                 // Field Companion:Lcom/gojek/driver/ulysses/email/di/EmailScreenFactoryModule$Companion;
      11: return

  public static final com.gojek.driver.ulysses.email.di.EnterEmailInjector providesEnterEmailInjector(com.gojek.driver.ulysses.driver.DriverProfileUsecase);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #40                 // Field Companion:Lcom/gojek/driver/ulysses/email/di/EmailScreenFactoryModule$Companion;
       3: aload_0
       4: invokevirtual #44                 // Method com/gojek/driver/ulysses/email/di/EmailScreenFactoryModule$Companion.providesEnterEmailInjector:(Lcom/gojek/driver/ulysses/driver/DriverProfileUsecase;)Lcom/gojek/driver/ulysses/email/di/EnterEmailInjector;
       7: areturn
}
```

Not really sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Covariance `? extends` is `out` in Kotlin. And Contravariance `? super` is `in` in Kotlin. Have a look at [Understanding Generics in Kotlin/Java](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47).

Comment: Kotlin has Covariance and Contravariance like told by @AnimeshSahu.  Can you elaborate problem you are facing with complete code.

Comment: In Java both type parameters are `? extends`, in Kotlin one `in` and one `out`. Both should be `out`.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu @alokHarman I even tried `out` in both of the cases, still dagger is throwing this issue `@Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type`

Answer (score 0):

Its actually a known issue, happens with Kotlin's out projected types. It is reported in dagger's [github issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1143).

As a work-around to solve the issue, the github issue and [this](https://medium.com/@naturalwarren/dagger-kotlin-3b03c8dd6e9b) article suggests to use `@JvmSuppressWildcards` to suppress warnings created by the compiler.

```kotlin
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ClassKey(EnterEmailFragment::class)
abstract fun bindsEnterEmailInjector(injector: EnterEmailInjector)
    : ScreenInjector<out @JvmSuppressWildcards Fragment, out @JvmSuppressWildcards Any>
```

Comment: This is also not working for me. Getting the same issue

Comment: @PrithviBhola what error message do you get now? Is it the same?

Comment: Yes @animesh-sahu